# Google login to SE login

Tags: support, login

I'm currently logging in to SO using my Google credentials. I'd rather login using a SE-specific profile. Is there any way to migrate profiles to use SO login credentials instead of Google login credentials?

Comment: also related from MSE: [Option to add a Stack Exchange Login to Existing Account has gone AWOL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234664/option-to-add-a-stack-exchange-login-to-existing-account-has-gone-awol)